# How to use R1C1 references in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting 1004 error in the following code, and I'm not sure why.

```
Public Function SetFormulaAndPasteVals(in_range As Range, formula_str As String, start_row As Long, end_row As Long)
    Dim start_cell As Range
    Dim in_col As Long
    in_col = in_range.Column
    ' This is where I get the error
    Set start_cell = in_range.Range("R" & start_row & "C" & in_col)
    start_cell.Formula = formula_str
    If start_row < end_row Then
        start_cell.Copy Destination:=in_range.Range("R" & start_row + 1 & "C" & in_col & ":R" & end_row & "C" & in_col)
    Else
        start_cell.Copy Destination:=in_range.Range("R" & start_row - 1 & in_col & "C" & in_col & ":R" & end_row & "C" & in_col)
    End If
    Call CopyPasteValues(in_range)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Function
```

I'm trying to avoid having to reference the column letter if it's possible.  I don't understand why it's not liking the R1C1 reference in the range function here.

Comment: Which particular part of this is giving you problems?  Do note that a *function* called from a worksheet can not perform the sort of copy/paste procedures taht you're trying to do here.

Comment: It's right after the comment, and no, this isn't meant to be used from a worksheet formula.

Comment: Probably easier to just use the `.Cells` method instead of tyring to finagle your way to R1C1 notation.  `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)` for instance is `Range("A1")`, and `.Cells(1, 2)` is `Range("B1")`, etc.

Comment: R1C1-style references are only for formulas.  You can use the `Cells` class to do what you are attempting.

Comment: Likewise, `inRange.Cells(1, 1)` would be the first row/column of the defined range object.  The other neat thing about `Cells` method is that you can use it to refer to cells *outside* of the range, i.e., `Range("A1").Cells(2, 1)` would be A2.

Comment: I would still observe that it's a bad practice to use a `Function` to manipulate the worksheet object. Typically functions are used to return values or assign to variables, whereas Subroutines are used to manipulate objects.

Comment: I can see that.  The difference between `Sub` and `Function` seem largely semantic to me except that `Sub` can't return anything.  To me it seems this seems this should be defined by scope rather than by function definition.

Comment: You could also use `Range.Offset()` to get where you want to go as well.

Comment: "It's not liking the R1C1 reference) because, according to **HELP** for worksheet.range object, the first argument is "*The name of the range. This must be an A1-style reference in the language of the macro. It can include the range operator (a colon), the intersection operator (a space), or the union operator (a comma). It can also include dollar signs, but they’re ignored. You can use a local defined name in any part of the range. If you use a name, the name is assumed to be in the language of the macro.*"